# TestCafe Studio: Is it possible to check smetrics records in the network tab of the Google Chrome dev tool through Deep equal assertion?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, e2e-testing, testcafe

This is regarding TestCafe studio feature to validate records like smetrics.vehicle.ca in the Network tab of the Google Chrome dev. It's basically more of interacting with Stack trace records in the Network tab(Image etc.) to validate through deep check assertion. Please list down the steps to validate?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your interest in TestCafe Studio.

[TestCafe Studio](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400157/testcafe-studio) is an instrument for end-to-end testing, whose purpose is to simulate the real user scenario and check that the system operates correctly. Working with Chrome Dev Tools is not supposed for end users, so TestCafe Studio does not support it.

In addition, I want to mention that since TestCafe Studio is commercial software, it's better to ask questions in DevExpress Support Center using the following [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create).